# Unable to uninstall an incompatible module

Tags: 7

I have 6.22 core and by mistake added the folder for quicktags 7.x-3.0 to the modules folder.

I deleted the folder, replaced it with 6.x but nothing seems to allow me to enable the quicktabs module under "Home » Administer » Site building » Modules."

All I get against the quicktab folder is:

> This version is incompatible with the 6.22 version of Drupal core.

How can I install the correct version of the module?

Comment: [quicktabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktags) doesn't have a version for Drupal 7, nor for Drupal 6. May you provide the link to the project page for the module you installed?

Comment: You almost certainly haven't uninstalled the module, or perhaps there were two of them in the filesystem. Do a search to find quick*.

Answer (score 1):

Install [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush), and type

```
drush cc all
```

to clear the cache, then

```
drush en quicktags
```

to enable the module; sometimes drush saves my day, when the admin>>modules throws errors.

Answer (score 0):

The only [quicktags](http://drupal.org/project/quicktags) module I found doesn't have a version for Drupal 6 and Drupal 7; the module is for Drupal 4.7 (the development snapshot 4.7.x-1.x-dev) and for Drupal 5 (the development snapshot 5.x-3.x-dev, and the official release 5.x-3.1-dev).

If you copied one of those versions, the module is rightly reported not to be compatible with Drupal 6.

If you installed [Quick Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs), which effectively has a 7.x-3-0 version, then it is probable that you have two copies of the files of that version in two different directories, one of which is the directory of another module. Suppose that you copy the files of the Quick Tabs module in the directory "cck," those files will be found first the files contained in the directory "quicktabs"; if the files copied in "cck" are for Drupal 7, then you see the error you are seeing because those files are the first ones that are retrieved.

Comment: There's too much confusion here about quicktags (with a 'g') and quicktabs (with a 'b'). Quicktabs is a popular module.

Comment: @rfay That is the module the OP reported to have installed.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion but it is quicktabs (with a b)

Answer (score 0):

I know that is an *old* question.

besides of clear cache and/or remove files, I find useful to review `.install` file of incompatible module to see in detail changes inside database, so you can detect respective changed data in database. Is just an opinion.